# What frameworks/solutions exist for scheduling and executing custom jobs

Tags: .net, scheduling

I am looking at implementing a lot of different configurable jobs (custom code) for scheduling. I will run custom code based on events, that will schedule other jobs for later execution.

Ie.

- run code at specific times
- run jobs after dependent jobs have succeeded
- retrying a number of times if something fails
- reporting (did something fail, what was the exception, how long did it run etc)
- alerting on errors

Now I can roll all this myself - but these are common requirements, so I figure something must already exist in this space.

Does something that fits this exist?

Preferably open source, but not a requirement.

Comment: Have you looked at [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)? First search result for ".net scheduling"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Damien posted in the comment, [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is one that will do much of what you are looking for and is open source.

> Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that
>   can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.